# OpenTK: Can I assume that all calls to OnUpdateFrame and OnRenderFrame will occur on the same thread?

Tags: opengl, opentk

Simple test showed it to be the case in one instance, but I need to make sure.  Is this property guaranteed by the OpenTK framework across all potential devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, UpdateFrame and RenderFrame events are guaranteed to be raised on the thread that created the GameWindow.